# Is $\int V^2e^{-V}d\text{vol}<\infty$ on a manifold such that $\text{Ric}+\text{Hess(V)}>0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a measure $\mu(dx)= e^{-V(x)}d\text{vol}$ on a Riemannian manifold M with $V\in C^2(M)$, $\int e^{-V}d\text{vol} = 1$ and $\text{Ric}+\text{Hess(V)}>0$.
Is it then true that $\int V^2e^{-V}d\text{vol}<\infty$?
This holds on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and of course on any compact manifold, which tempts me to believe that it is always true, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: May I know how this is true for $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: My attempt on $\mathbb{R}^n$: $V$ is coercive and thus bounded from below.
  Let $k_0:= \lfloor \inf V\rfloor>-\infty$ and, for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $A_k := \left\{k\leq V<k+1\right\}$. \\
  $V$ grows at least linearly at infinity so that there is some $M>>0$ with $\text{vol}(A_k)\leq Mk^{n-1}$ for all $k$.
  Thus,
  \begin{align*}
   \int V^2e^{-V} d x
   \leq \sum_{k=k_0}^\infty (k+1)^2e^{-k}\text{vol}(A_k)
   \leq M \sum_{k=k_0}^\infty (k+1)^2e^{-k}k^{n-1}
   < \infty
  ,\end{align*}
  where the last sum is finite by the integral test for convergence.